# How do I get a context menu to work on a Telerik RadGridView column?

Tags: wpf, telerik, contextmenu, radgridview

I have the following method which adds a new column to a Telerik RadGridView:

```
private void CreateNewColumn(FieldDescriptor fd, uint fieldno) {
    fieldGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn() {
        UniqueName = fd.fieldName,
        Header = fd.displayName,
        DataMemberBinding = new Binding("Fields[" + fieldno + "]"),
        ContextMenu = new ContextMenu() {
            Tag = fieldno,
            Items = {
                new MenuItem() {
                    Header = "Field Properties",
                    Command = Commands.FieldProperties,
                    CommandBindings = { new CommandBinding(Commands.FieldProperties, FieldProperties_Execute) } 
                },
                new MenuItem() {
                    Header = "Delete Field",
                    Command = Commands.DeleteField,
                    CommandBindings = { new CommandBinding(Commands.DeleteField, DeleteField_Execute) }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the context menu never appears when I right click anywhere on the grid. If I bind the context menu directly to the grid, i.e.

```
fieldGrid.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu() { ...
```

then the context menu shows up, but I have no way of determining which column the user right-clicked on. Has anyone gotten context menus to work on individual columns or column headers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check my answer on your forum post:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/column-contextmenu.aspx

Comment: Posting code rather than a link, which in turn refers to another link, would be better

Comment: especially when this other link posts to a page where you have to download software in order to code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for Telerik's grid, but with the Infragistics grid you would attach the context menu to the grid, and then use the mouse location to determine what the user right clicked on in the grid.  The Infragistics grid has some decent helper methods to facilitate the hit testing.